# How to create a Custom Indexer?

Tags: magento-1.9, indexer

I'm trying to create a custom indexer for a particular product attribute.
I need to:

- read the product attribute value
- process it in some way ( not relevant )
- save it in a index table

The above steps could be implemented in a custom script but I would like integrate the indexer using the patter used by other indexer in Magento.

I can see that Magento default indexer implement this abstract class `Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract`
... It looks not easy to understand the process from the code and I cannot find any documentation for it.

Any help is appreciate thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Following info should be a generic guide line that lead to a basic understanding of the whole `indexer thing`, so are not a complete 'walkthrough' ... ( if you want to contribute to this answer you are welcome )

There are at least 3 steps required here:

1. Create an index table and related resource model
2. Create an Indexer model that implement `Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract`
3. add your indexer to Magento configuration

Suggested documentation:

1. Probably the best way to dig into this is to give a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Price` ( this is one of the easier index implementation ).
2. [This resource](http://www.mexbs.com/creating-custom-magento-index/), at the moment, looks the best guide to understand the whole process to decide what it is the action that is required.

**STEP 1**
Just add your index table in the installer, as for any other module table.
Your resource model needs to implement the logic for `Reindex All` in the `reindexAll()` method: you would probably process all entities here an extract all data.

**STEP 2**
`_registerEvent()`,`_processEvent()` are the important method here, you will need to dig a bit in the below guide to understand the logic behind them

Basically `_registerEvent()` add some data to the `$event`, on the base of the 'event type' and the 'entity type'. This extra data will be used in `_processEvent()` method.

You will need to implement at least the following methods in your model.

```
/**
 * Data key for matching result to be saved in
 */
const EVENT_MATCH_RESULT_KEY = 'some_key';

/**
 * Initialize resource model
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('module/resource_model');
}

/**
 * @var  Used by matchEvent()
 * for example if you are processing products ...
 */
protected $_matchedEntities = array(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY => array(
        Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE,
        Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_MASS_ACTION,
        Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_DELETE
    )
);

 /**
 * Get Indexer name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName(){
    return 'My indexer Name';
}

/**
 * Get Indexer description
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return 'My indexer Description';
}

/**
 * Register indexer required data inside event object
 *
 * @param   Mage_Index_Model_Event $event
 *
 * Register data required by process in event object
 * @param Mage_Index_Model_Event $event
 */
protected function _registerEvent(Mage_Index_Model_Event $event)
{
    $event->addNewData(self::EVENT_MATCH_RESULT_KEY, true);
    $entity = $event->getEntity();
    $dataObj = $event->getDataObject();

    if ($entity == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY) {
        if ($event->getType() == Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE) {
            $event->addNewData('yourmodule_update_product_id', $dataObj->getId());
        } elseif ($event->getType() == Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_DELETE) {
            $event->addNewData(' yourmodule _delete_product_id', $dataObj->getId());
        } elseif ($event->getType() == Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_MASS_ACTION) {
            $event->addNewData(' yourmodule _mass_action_product_ids', $dataObj->getProductIds());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Process event based on event state data
 *
 * @param   Mage_Index_Model_Event $event
 */
protected function _processEvent(Mage_Index_Model_Event $event){
    /** DO STUFF **/
    return $this;
}
```

**STEP 3**
Add this to your configuration, [module/model] is the model created in step 2.
So at this point if you go in system->indexer you will see a new entry

```
<global>
    ......
    <index>
        <indexer>
            <some_key>
                <model>module/model</model>
            </some_key>
        </indexer>
    </index>
    ......
</global>
```

**Sources:**

- http://www.mexbs.com/creating-custom-magento-index/
- http://blog.magestore.com/2012/07/20/magento-certificate-custom-index/
- http://www.slideshare.net/ivanchepurnyi/magento-indexes